# Subversion: versioned directory showing up as not versioned in svn status

Tags: svn, version-control

I recently deleted a directory from a local working copy and later followed up with an svn co on that directory from the central repository. Now if I do svn status, that particular directory shows up with a '?', meaning it is not under version control. If I run svn add on the directory, I get an svn: warning: directory is already under version control. I've added --force, but it still shows up as not versioned.

How does one recover from this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Use `svn revert`:

```
svn revert -R yourdir
```

The `-R` recurses into subdirectories.

Comment: Running svn revert -R on the culprit directory still has the directory showing up as not versioned in svn status.

Comment: @randombits: Ok, try deleting the directory from your working copy and *then* revert.

Comment: Greg: I did an rm -fr mydir; svn revert -R mydir, still no luck. Revert doesn't bring back the directory at all in this case.. I'd have to use svn co.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but I believe I haven an answer that can help other people.

**The cause**
This can can occur when you copy a folder attached to svn (it will have an .svn subfolder inside) and place it somewhere else in your project.

**The reason**
It will have the folder contents (files/subfolders) attached to the old svn location; thus any files inside are versioned, and will be committed to the old location when you do so.

However the folder itself is not present in its parent folder svn information; thus it will show up as unversioned, but when trying to add this folder it will detect the svn settings in the folder in question and refuse to add it saying it is already versioned.

**The possible fix**
So to 'fix' this problem if you copied the folder from an other versioned directory you can either.

A. Remove the .svn folder in this directory AND all subdirectories.

B. Remove the folder in question; and properly copy it from its original location.

**How to properly copy a folder in svn to another svn dir.**

1. Export the directory to the target parent directory using the svn
   export (on command line)
2. If you just want to move the directory you should use `svn mv` instead (svn 'move' on command line)

Answer (score -1):

```
svn co svn://path/deleted_folder
```

should do the trick assuming that you have not recreated the deleted_folder with mkdir.

Comment: If you take a look at my original post, you will see I already did that.